# PureScript Could not match type Maybe Int with type Int

Tags: purescript

I am doing the assignment in the book "PureScript by example" to use recursion to count the number of even items in an array.

Here is the code I wrote

```
isEven :: Int -> Boolean
isEven 0 = true
isEven 1 = false
isEven n = isEven(n - 2) 

countEven :: List Int -> Int
countEven list = 
   if null list 
   then 0
   else 
      if isEven(unsafePartial (head list)) 
      then 1 
      else 0 + countEven(unsafePartial (tail list))
```

I get an error message saying

```
Error found:
in module Main
at src/Main.purs line 74, column 17 - line 74, column 42

  Could not match type

    Maybe Int

  with type

    Int


while checking that type t0
  is at least as general as type Int
while checking that expression unsafePartial (head list)
  has type Int
in binding group countEven
```

I am a little surprised by this because the data types of`unsafePartial head list` is Int and `unsafePartial tail list` is List Int

So why does it feel that there is a Maybe somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that you're getting this error means that you're using [`head`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-lists/4.8.0/docs/Data.List#v:head) and [`tail`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-lists/4.8.0/docs/Data.List#v:tail) from `Data.List`, which are not actually partial, but return a `Maybe`.

To use their partial counterparts, import them from [`Data.List.Partial`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-lists/4.8.0/docs/Data.List.Partial).

Comment: If I am using the head from Data.List.head and Dta.List.Partial.head how do I disambiguate them?

Comment: Use qualified imports.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `uncons` instead of using such a heavy hammer as `unsafePartial` because it can easily slip out of your hand...

If you really want to write this recursion by hand (which I consider an antipattern) you can write it as follows:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Array (uncons)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))

isEven :: Int -> Boolean
isEven n = n `mod` 2 == 0

countEven l =
  case uncons l of
    Just { head, tail } ->
      let
        s =
         if isEven head
         then 1
         else 0
      in
        s + countEven tail
    Nothing -> 0
```

Here is interactive version of this snippet on [try.purescript.org](http://try.purescript.org/?session=38b8ea1d-65a5-c69f-cfd5-42cd662b6961&backend=core&gist=802b0151e8dec33b57508d4afecfd479).

As I said above you should avoid `unsafePartial` and `Partial` as they destroy confidence in your program totality. Totality is **really valuable** feature of any program.
In general I think that it is much better to use higher level tools such a `fold` or [`foldMap` + `ala`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-newtype/blob/master/src/Data/Newtype.purs#L44) than "raw recursion assembly".